# Web scraping <strong><abbr title="Wednesday">Wed</abbr>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to learn web scraping by using bs4 and having a little trouble with getting the date of the week.

This is what I have currently:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/bc-74_metric_e.html')
html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

forecast = html.find(class_="visible-xs mrgn-tp-md")

print(forecast.find_all("strong"))
```

I would like to get the following outputs:

```
Tonight
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
Sun
Mon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here (tested in python 3):

```
 counter = 0
 for i in forecast.find_all("strong"):
     if counter == 0:
             print(i.text)
     elif i.find("abbr"):
             print(i.text.split(',')[0])
     counter=1
```

Or, if you want to get rid of the branching:

```
 strong_contents = forecast.find_all("strong")
 values = []
 # first element is Tonight without "abbr" 
 values.append(strong_contents[0].text)
 # Use list slicing to get the rest of the elements and filter by "abbr"
 for i in strong_contents[1:]:
     if i.find("abbr"):
             # i.text gives "Wed, 6 Oct", so we split by `,` 
             # and print first element
             values.append(i.text.split(',')[0])
 print('\n'.join(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```
strong_tag = forecast.find_all("strong")

days = [strong_tag[0].contents[0]]

for i in strong_tag:
    if i.find("abbr"):
        days.append(i.getText())
```

If we print the `days` list, the output is like this:

```
print("\n".join(days))
```

output:

```
Tonight
Wed, 6 Oct
Thu, 7 Oct
Fri, 8 Oct
Sat, 9 Oct
Sun, 10 Oct
Mon, 11 Oct
```

> If you only want the names of the days, you can use `days.append(i.getText().split(",")[0])` instead of `days.append(i.getText())`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner, I did try to figure out your expected output. If I do any mistake please correct me. You can try the below code to get the output. I hope it will be helpful for you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/bc-74_metric_e.html')
html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

forecast = html.find(class_="visible-xs mrgn-tp-md")

data = forecast.find_all("strong")

store = []

for i in data:
    store.append(i.get_text())
    
# print(store)
    
keyword = ['Tonight', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue']

for i in store:
    for j in keyword:
        if str(j) in str(i):
            print(i.split(',',1)[0])
```

Output:

```
Tonight
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
Sun
Mon
```

And to get the below output:

```
Tonight
Wed, 6 Oct
Thu, 7 Oct
Fri, 8 Oct
Sat, 9 Oct
Sun, 10 Oct
Mon, 11 Oct
```

You need to change a little `print(i)` instead of `print(i.split(',',1)[0])`

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  I should have clarified in your OP that I was trying to avoid the creating a list like the keyword one.  

I think my first mistake in creating my web scraper was not using the "strong" class to narrow down what I need.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternativ selection

Select `<table>` that contains `class` named `textforcast` and all its `<strong>`:

```
forecast = html.select('table.textforecast strong')
```

#### Select day of week abbreviation incl tonight as list

```
[x.get_text().split(',')[0] for x in forecast]
```

Output list:

```
['Tonight', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon']
```

Print just values:

```
print(*[x.get_text().split(',')[0] for x in forecast], sep = "\n")

Tonight
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
Sun
Mon
```

#### Select dates as list

```
[' '.join(x.get_text().split('\xa0')) for x in forecast]
```

Output list:

```
['Tonight',
 'Wed, 6 Oct',
 'Thu, 7 Oct',
 'Fri, 8 Oct',
 'Sat, 9 Oct',
 'Sun, 10 Oct',
 'Mon, 11 Oct']
```

Print just values:

```
print(*[' '.join(x.get_text().split('\xa0')) for x in forecast] for x in forecast], sep = "\n")

Tonight
Wed, 6 Oct
Thu, 7 Oct
Fri, 8 Oct
Sat, 9 Oct
Sun, 10 Oct
Mon, 11 Oct
```

#### Full example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/bc-74_metric_e.html')
html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

forecast = html.select('table.textforecast strong')

print(*[x.get_text().split(',')[0] for x in forecast], sep = "\n")
```

#### Output

```
Tonight
Wed
Thu
Fri
Sat
Sun
Mon
```